# WordPress gutenberg custom block fails to render

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block

I'm trying to rewrite a Short-Code to a Gutenberg block.  I'm not experienced in React, though I've been coding Angular 2+ since 2017.

I created my block with the following command:

```
> npx @wordpress/create-block give-camp-blocks-plugin
```

I built and ran it.  My block visually edits fine.
I can use the browser inspect and it has the appropriate HTML.
But, switching to 'code editor' and the all that is rendered is the following:

```
<!-- wp:create-block/give-camp-blocks-plugin /-->
```

And, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at l (http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=90cebfec01d1a3f0368e:2:19718)
    at Object.__unstableMarkListeningStores (http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=90cebfec01d1a3f0368e:2:20176)
    at http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=90cebfec01d1a3f0368e:9:2223
    at p (http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=90cebfec01d1a3f0368e:9:2121)
    at http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=90cebfec01d1a3f0368e:9:2214
    at $e (http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=90cebfec01d1a3f0368e:9:2643)
    at Be (http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=90cebfec01d1a3f0368e:9:2964)
    at hs (http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/editor.min.js?ver=f49ef02c2dddb31edd0e:19:124768)
    at kt (http://localhost:9139/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:47633)
```

I stripped the implementation down to the bare minimum as follows:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
import metadata from './block.json';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
//
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
  apiVersion: metadata.apiVersion,
  title: metadata.title,
  //
  edit: ( { attributes, setAttributes } ) => {
    const { content } = attributes;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( {
      className: "gc-marquee"
    } );
    blockProps['role'] = 'marquee';
    blockProps['aria-label'] = __(content);
    //
    return (
      <>
      <div
        { ...blockProps }
        >
        <RichText
          className="gc-scrollingtext"
          aria-hidden="true"
          tagName="p"
          placeholder={ 'Write text here ...' }
          value={ content }
          onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { content: value } ) }
        />
      </div>
      </>
    );
  },
  save: ( { attributes } ) => {
    const { content } = attributes;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( {
      className: "gc-marquee"
    } );
    blockProps['role'] = 'marquee';
    blockProps['aria-label'] = __(content);
    //
    return (
      <>
      <div
        { ...blockProps }
        >
        <RichText.Content
          className="gc-scrollingtext"
          aria-hidden="true"
          tagName="p"
          value={ content }
        />
      </div>
      </>
    );
  },
} );
```

The following is a snippet of block.json:

```
{
    ...
    "attributes": {
        "content":  {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "p",
            "default": ""
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

When I click publish and refresh the page is corrupt and nothing displays.  Not the title, not the sidebar, nothing displays.  I'm at a lose of what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers in the [Gutenberg examples](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples).  So, this is what my bare minimum example now looks like:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
import metadata from './block.json';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
//
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
  apiVersion: metadata.apiVersion,
  title: metadata.title,
  //
  edit: ( props ) => {
    const {
      attributes: { content, padding },
      setAttributes,
    } = props;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( {
      className: "gc-marquee"
    } );
    blockProps['role'] = 'marquee';
    blockProps['aria-label'] = __(content);
    //
    return (
      <div
        { ...blockProps }
        >
        <RichText
          className="gc-scrollingtext"
          aria-hidden="true"
          tagName="p"
          placeholder={ 'Write text here ...' }
          value={ content }
          onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { content: value } ) }
        />
      </div>
    );
  },
  //
  // <!-- wp:give-camp/gc-test-sample -->
  // <div class="wp-block-give-camp-gc-test-sample gc-marquee" aria-label="ace" role="marquee">
  //  <p class="gc-scrollingtext" aria-hidden="true">ace</p>
  // </div>
  // <!-- /wp:give-camp/gc-test-sample -->
  //
  save: ( props ) => {
    const {
      attributes: { content }
    } = props;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( {
      className: "gc-marquee"
    } );
    blockProps['role'] = 'marquee';
    blockProps['aria-label'] = __(content);
    //
    return (
      <div
        { ...blockProps }
        >
        <RichText.Content
          className="gc-scrollingtext"
          aria-hidden="true"
          tagName="p"
          value={ content }
        />
      </div>
    );
  },
} );
```

I removed the following:

```
<>
...
</>
```

I changed the call to **edit** and **save** to use props, but I don't know if that really did anything...

So, I got the bare minimum example to work, but the real code still didn't work.  Back to the Gutenberg examples, I finally got the real code to work changing the **edit** function (I thought it would be in the save, but it wasn't).

```
return (
  <div
    { ...blockProps }
    style={ {
      backgroundColor: bg_color, color: text_color, fontSize: font_size,
      padding: `${padding.top} ${padding.right} ${padding.bottom} ${padding.left}`
    } }
    >
    {
      <InspectorControls key="setting">
        <PanelBody
          ...
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>
    }
    <RichText
      className="gc-scrollingtext"
      style={ { margin: 0, } }
      aria-hidden="true"
      tagName="p"
      data-milli-sec={ milli_sec }
      value={ __(content) }
      placeholder={ placeholder }
      onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { content: value } ) }
    />
  </div>
);
```

I had to place a class {} around the InspectorControls.

Also, make sure in the **save** method, that one uses the save method for useBlockProps.save and the Content method for controls like RichText.Content and InnerBlocks.Content.

Also, in the usage of wp.i18n __ method.  The second parameter is the text domain, that is found in block.json.  I get the value and use it in the method as follows:

```
title={ __('Millisecond delay', textdomain ) }
```

EsLint does not like textdomain, because it is a variable.

Comment: I'm surprised it worked without ever closing this:  <PanelBody  ...</PanelBody> but I don't understand Wordpress blocks!

Comment: The numerous PanelBody were removed for brevity.  Each value in the style had an appropriate control.